# Postgresql want to run a query for each day in an interval

Tags: postgresql

i have a query which i need to run for every day in an interval, like for each day, for the last 2 years, i don't have the day info in the table, so i need to do it in a loop i think:

```
'    select distinct on (osu.order_id) osu.order_id, osu.order_state, osu.created_at
      from stock_management.order_state_updates osu
      where osu.created_at < '2021-01-26 22:00:00'
      order by osu.order_id desc, osu.created_at desc) temp
     where temp.order_state = 'Filter1';'
```

in which the date '2021-01-26 22:00:00' would go through each day of the interval. thank you

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B2xx-c3wWZYaEN76LxjYhHnlrPRUx4TG8vsAkZ1X_Vs/edit?usp=sharing

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjmKT.png)

Comment: Do you have some examples? From data, but also expected output. Please use https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14

Comment: This is going to return over 700 results set with 99% duplicated data. I suggest that you think again about what you want to find or show and redefine your need.

Comment: i want to have a timestamp for each day, so i can check if the sales was not poor because of the stock lack. i was thimking at another angle, to take the current stock ,add the sales and extract the acquisitions., but i thought that i woul first try this version with saving it each day

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a calendar and join it to your query. I'm not sure this will retrieve the right datas because I don't have sample data and expected result.

```
with d as (select * from generate_series ('20210101','20220427',interval '1 day') as date)
select distinct on (osu.order_id) osu.order_id, osu.order_state, osu.created_at::date
from stock_management.order_state_updates osu right join d on osu.created_at::date = d.date
order by osu.order_id desc, osu.created_at desc) temp
where temp.order_state = 'Filter1';
```

Comment: thank you for your answear , it gives me an error when i've tryed to run it i will attach it to the post. thank you

Comment: i put also sample data

Comment: Send sample datas as editable text never as images.

Comment: google sheets it is ok? i am new and learning

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: can you please tell me how to use generate_series to create date like 2021-14-17 05:00? thank you

Comment: your script it is super fine, but i would need only modification , if you can , it returns the records what where created in the same day in the join, but i need values where osu.created_at < '2021-01-26 22:00:00', all the values valid till that day. thank you

Comment: Just add a condition on created date `...right join d on osu.created_at::date = d.date and osu.created_at < '2021-01-26 22:00:00'`